# Swagger PHP Security Schema referenced poorly

Tags: swagger-php

I'm using this SecuritySchema for definind a JWT security validation:

```
/*
     * @SWG\SecurityScheme(
     *   securityDefinition="JWT",
     *   type="apiKey",
     *   in="header",
     *   name="Authenticate"
     * ) */
```

And referencing it as:

```
/*
 * @SWG\Post(path="/ap/some/method",
 *   security={"JWT"={}},
 * )
```

and the specifications says I should reference as

```
{
...
"security":["JWT":[]]
...
}
```

but the truth is that Swagger-PHP generates:

```
{
...
"security":{"JWT":[]}
...
}
```

which shows as validation errors on Swagger UI.

The question is: 
**How do I emulate the desired output to avoid Swagger UI AND Swagger PHP warnings/errors?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`security":["JWT":[]]` isn't valid json, but the specification does require an array for the security property.

The desired output is:

```
"security":[{"JWT":[]}]
```

Which can be generated by:

```
security={{"JWT":{}}}
```

*(note the additional brackets)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did it!